# Why I cannot "await" an Async method from Atlassian SDK?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sdk

I am desperately trying to run the following code:

```
var ad = jira.Issues.GetIssuesFromJqlAsync("PROJECT = MyProject AND ISSUETYPE = DEFECT");
```

The signature of the method is `Task<IPagedQueryResult<Issue>>` ([documentation link](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/be7a9a739da78141963782f1a730cb3d9c05c925/Atlassian.Jira/IIssueService.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) )

The method should be async but I cannot use "await" (I get the error that the method needs to be marked with async and return task..). I am able to execute it by calling `ad.start()` but that is not asynchronous.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is the method you are calling this from marked with `async`?

Comment: @maccettura That has no bearing on whether you can await it.  Also, unless that library is open source, they have no way of knowing (because that's a private implementation detail of that method).

Comment: @Servy Straight from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await): `"await can only be used in an asynchronous method modified by the async keyword."`  OP said they cannot use `await` which makes me feel like the method that this code lives in is not marked `async`

Comment: "but that is not asynchronous"  How so?  That sure sounds asynchronous to me.

Comment: @Servy so I do not need to use "await" and it will be async?

Comment: @JohnV That depends on what the method returns, and how it behaves.  If it's not blocking, which it doesn't sound like it is, then it's asynchronous.  What you need to do to run code when that asynchronous operation finishes will depend on how the calling method/object were designed.

Comment: @Servy Don't you await `Task`s? So if `GetIssuesFromJqlAsync` returns a `Task`, then it should be awaitable, and as maccettura stated, the method containing this code would need to be marked `async`.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Also, what's the signature of `GetIssuesFromJqlAsync`?

Comment: @KennethK. It doesn't sound like the method returns a `Task` at all, given the description.

Comment: @Servy but [it does](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/be7a9a739da78141963782f1a730cb3d9c05c925/Atlassian.Jira/IIssueService.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), it specifically returns a `Task<IPagedQueryResult<Issue>>`

Comment: Found some [source](https://searchcode.com/file/128952311/Atlassian.Jira/Remote/IssueService.cs#l-66) confirming the same

Answer (score -1):

mark you method Async. if you dont need the return it dosnt need to be a task,

it should look like:

```
public async Task<string> YourMethod()
{
    var ad = await jira.Issues.GetIssuesFromJqlAsync("PROJECT = MyProject AND ISSUETYPE = DEFECT");
    return ad.ToString();
}
```

if you want the return, or:

```
async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  var ad = await jira.Issues.GetIssuesFromJqlAsync("PROJECT = MyProject AND ISSUETYPE = DEFECT");

}
```

for a more in depth explanation here are the [docs...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: The method should return Task.

Comment: not absolutely, it just cant be void, but if you insist

Comment: It can be void, but it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: both right, better to have an empty task. you just don't absolutely need a return.

Comment: this is probably the solution to OP's problem. For more information @John V : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624647/why-use-async-when-i-have-to-use-await .
Note : you will probably need to use async / await methods all the way up the call chain - see this very informative article from Stephen Cleary on async and await : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx